# Why does interface return object instead of generic parameter type?

Tags: c#, generic-interface

```cs
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
public interface IEndpointFilter
{
    ValueTask<object?> InvokeAsync(EndpointFilterInvocationContext context, EndpointFilterDelegate next);
}
```

I am wondering why the above interface is not made as follows?

```cs
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
public interface<T> IEndpointFilter
{
    ValueTask<T?> InvokeAsync(EndpointFilterInvocationContext context, EndpointFilterDelegate next);
}
```

Comment: Probably because all IEndpointFilters registered on [EndpointFilterExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.endpointfilterextensions?view=aspnetcore-7.0) would still need to be generic only over `object` to cater for all `T`s, so it doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: Generic interfaces are nice when you implement them, but hard to use - for example, imagine you want to have list of `IEndpointFilter` - what will be its type? If not generic, then its `List<IEndpointFilter>` and if generic - `List<IEndpointFilter<???>>`. Generic interfaces are convinient when you then provide them into generic classes or methods. If you want to use generics in this case - you can create base generic class, say `EndpointFilter<T>` which will implement `IEndpointFilter` and make `InvokeAsync` use specific type.

Comment: @Quercus: How do you implement non-generic `IEndpointFilter` with a generic class? The generic class method `InvokeAsync` still returns `ValueTask<object?>`.

Comment: @TheRealMasochist You can create T-specific method `ValueTask<T?> InvokeAsync` and explicitly implement interface method: `ValueTask<object?> IEndpointFilter.InvokeAsync` which simply calls first (T-specific) method.

Comment: @Quercus: So your approach will still have boxing-unboxing drawback, right?

Comment: @TheRealMasochist Sure, there will be boxing-unboxing for value types.

Answer (score 0):

while using generic type, you force the developer to use a type to implement the methods which may be confusing or not necessary here